# drawbacks of getStaticPaths empty array and fallback true?

Tags: next.js

I have thousands of pages that should be rendered serverside in my next.js app. As you can imagine, it takes a lot of time to build. What are the drawbacks of returning an empty array in getStaticPaths and setting fallback to true?

Answer (score 1):

`fallback: true` is not supported when using `next export` so you would need to start NextJs server with `next start` or make your own server that starts NextJs process. Sometimes it is a drawback, for example you might want to build all the pages beforehand and put them on CDN or something.

Also first user hitting that page might need to wait a little bit longer before the page is generated. Subsequent request will serve the generated page, just like other pages pre-rendered at build time.

Also, `fallback: true` will not update generated pages, for that take a look at [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration), specifically `revalidate` option for `getStaticProps`.